# How to change MarkerCluster icon colour but keep the original icon design

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a large web project with an interactive map where everything works fine. The final elements to do are styling and I would like to simply (or so I thought it was) change the colour of the default ClusterMarker. I really like the aesthetic of the circles with the number of elements in the cluster over it but would like to have 8/9 different colours, not the default 3 (green, yellow and red).

I've tried following numerous stackoverflow answers and the documentation but none of the answers work.

Below is what I currently have:

```
var markersEU = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    showCoverageOnHover: false,
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        var t = cluster.getChildCount();
        return new L.divIcon(
            {
                html: "<div><span>" + t + "</span></div>",
                className: "leaflet-marker-icon marker-cluster marker-cluster-eu leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive",
                iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40)
            }
        );
    }
});
```

And here is the `MarkerCluster.Default.css` file

```
.marker-cluster-small {
    background-color: rgba(181, 226, 140, 0.6);
    }
.marker-cluster-small div {
    background-color: rgba(110, 204, 57, 0.6);
    }

.marker-cluster-medium {
    background-color: rgba(241, 211, 87, 0.6);
    }
.marker-cluster-medium div {
    background-color: rgba(240, 194, 12, 0.6);
    }

.marker-cluster-large {
    background-color: rgba(253, 156, 115, 0.6);
    }
.marker-cluster-large div {
    background-color: rgba(241, 128, 23, 0.6);
    }

.marker-cluster-eu {
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 206, 0.6);
    }
.marker-cluster-eu div{
    background-color: rgba(35, 35, 200, 0.6);
    }

    /* IE 6-8 fallback colors */
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-small {
    background-color: rgb(181, 226, 140);
    }
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-small div {
    background-color: rgb(110, 204, 57);
    }

.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-medium {
    background-color: rgb(241, 211, 87);
    }
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-medium div {
    background-color: rgb(240, 194, 12);
    }

.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-large {
    background-color: rgb(253, 156, 115);
    }
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-large div {
    background-color: rgb(241, 128, 23);
}

.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-eu {
    background-color: rgb(74, 74, 206);
    }
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-eu div{
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 200);
}

.marker-cluster {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }
.marker-cluster div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;

    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
.marker-cluster span {
    line-height: 30px;
    }
```

As you can see, I haven't changed anything in the default styling other than added my own `marker-cluster-eu` styling.

Here is the github where everything is (if it helps find a solution): https://github.com/MaxMichel2/PWEB

To make things perfectly clear, I would like to keep EVERYTHING default about the clusters and their aesthetics and ONLY change the colour.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried on an example in the GitHub repository of the markercluster library, copy/paste your `iconCreateFunction` and your two extra CSS rules, and I have the clusters in blue.

Comment: @MaxMichel sounds like you should edit your question to explain more specifically what you are missing, compared to the code sample you provide.

Comment: @ghybs I have nothing different than what is up there which is my issue. I don't understand why it works with Joffrey but not me...

Comment: If you could reproduce your issue (e.g. in https://leafletjs.com/edit), that would tremendously help.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it which leads me to believe that the issue is more complex than I initially thought. I'll keep trying and update this question when I manage to do so. Thank you @ghybs